Can't send the quiz score from my js code to the server
Im trying to send the quiz score from my js code to my learner controller so I can insert the score in the result table and display the result to the user.
I tried to create a hidden form and set the input hidden inside the form with the score from my js and than request it from the server but still giving errors
The errors:

POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/submit_quiz 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

app.py
# learner show exam
@app.route('/learner_show_exam', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required(role='Learner')
def learner_show_exam():
    return learner_dashboard_controller.show_exam()

# learner submit result
@app.route('/submit_quiz', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required(role='Learner')
def submit_quiz():
    return learner_dashboard_controller.submit_result()

learner_controller.py:
#============================================================================
    # show exam
    #============================================================================  
    def show_exam(self):
        try:
            if request.headers.get('X-Requested-With') == 'XMLHttpRequest':
                learner_implementation = UserService()
                quiz_implementation = QuizService()
                learner_id = session.get('user_id')
                user_data = learner_implementation.getLearnerDataById(learner_id)
                lang = user_data[12]
                level = user_data[13]
                quiz_data = quiz_implementation.read_all_quizzes_data_by_lang_level(lang, level)

                data = {
                    'quiz_data': quiz_data,
                }

                return jsonify(data)
            
            learner_id = session.get('user_id')
            learner_implementation = UserService()
            user_picture = learner_implementation.getLearnerDataById(learner_id)

            return render_template("learner/exam/show_exam.html", profil_picture=user_picture)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An error occurred while showing the exam: {e}")
            # Handle the error gracefully, you may want to return an error page or message.
            return "An error occurred while showing the exam."
    
    #logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    #logging.error("An error occurred while submitting quiz: %s", e)
    
    def submit_result():
        try:
            if request.method == 'POST':
                # Get form data
                user_id = session.get('user_id')
                learner_implementation = UserService()
                quiz_implementation = QuizService()
                user_data = learner_implementation.getLearnerDataById(user_id)
                lang = user_data[12]
                level = user_data[13]
                quiz_data = quiz_implementation.read_all_quizzes_data_by_lang_level(lang, level)
                quiz_id = quiz_data[0]
                score = request.form.get('score')
                
                print("quiz id: " , quiz_id)
                print("score: " , score)

                if score >= 70:  # Check if score is 70% or higher
                    passed = True
                else:
                    passed = False

                result = Result()

                # Set Result object properties
                result.set_user_id(user_id)
                result.set_quiz_id(quiz_id)
                result.set_score(score)
                result.set_passed(passed)

                result_implementation = ResultService()
                if result_implementation.create_result(result):
                    return jsonify({'success': True})
                else:
                    return jsonify({'success': False, 'message': 'Une erreur s\'est produite. Veuillez réessayer'})
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error:", e)
            return jsonify({'success': False, 'message': str(e)})


html code:
<h1 id="scroll" class="title">Examin et Resultat</h1>
<ul class="breadcrumbs">
    <li><a href="#">Examin & Resultat</a></li>
    <li class="divider">/</li>
    <li><a href="#" class="active">Examin</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="table">
    <div id="scroll-table" class="table-header">
        <p>Repond aux quiz pour passez l'examin</p>
    </div>
    <div id="feedback_message"></div>
    <div id="loading-spinner">
        <div class="alert alert-info">
            <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Chargement en cours...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="quiz_data"></div>
<form id="score-form" class="needs-validation" method="post" novalidate style="display:none;">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" id="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="score" id="score">
    <input type="submit" id="submit-btn" style="display: none;">
</form>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script async src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/learner/exam/show_exam_client_side.js') }}"></script>

show_exam_client_side.js code:
const quizContainer = document.getElementById("quiz_data");

let currentQuestionIndex = 0;
let score = 0;
let questions = []; // Array to store fetched questions

function fetchQuizesData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/learner_show_exam',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',

        success: function (response) {
            $('html, body').css('cursor', 'default');
            $('.pagination-link').removeClass('loading');

            questions = response.quiz_data;

            $('#loading-spinner').hide();
            startQuiz();
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown);
            $('html, body').css('cursor', 'default');
            $('.pagination-link').removeClass('loading');
        }
    });
}

function startQuiz() {
    currentQuestionIndex = 0;
    score = 0;
    showQuestion();
}

function showQuestion() {
    const shuffledAnswers = shuffleArray(questions[currentQuestionIndex].slice(2));
    const correctAnswerIndex = shuffledAnswers.findIndex(answer => answer === questions[currentQuestionIndex][2]);
    const quizHtml = `
        <div class="app">
            <div class="quiz">
                <h2 id="question">${currentQuestionIndex + 1}. ${questions[currentQuestionIndex][1]}</h2>
                <div id="answer-buttons">
                    ${shuffledAnswers.map((answer, index) => `
                        <button class="btn answer-btn" data-correct="${index === correctAnswerIndex}">${answer}</button>
                    `).join('')}
                </div>
                <button id="next-btn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="display: none;">Suivant</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    `;

    quizContainer.innerHTML = quizHtml;

    const nextButton = document.getElementById("next-btn");

    // Attach event listener to dynamically created buttons
    document.querySelectorAll('.answer-btn').forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener('click', selectAnswer);
    });

    nextButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        currentQuestionIndex++;
        if (currentQuestionIndex < questions.length) {
            showQuestion();
        } else {
            showScore();
        }
    });
}

// Function to shuffle an array
function shuffleArray(array) {
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
    }
    return array;
}

function selectAnswer(e) {
    const selectedBtn = e.target;
    const isCorrect = selectedBtn.dataset.correct === "true";
    if (isCorrect) {
        selectedBtn.classList.add("correct");
        score++;
    } else {
        selectedBtn.classList.add("incorrect");
    }
    const answerButtons = document.getElementById('answer-buttons');
    Array.from(answerButtons.children).forEach(button => {
        if (button.dataset.correct === "true") {
            button.classList.add("correct");
        }
        button.disabled = true;
    });
    const nextButton = document.getElementById("next-btn");
    nextButton.style.display = "block";
}

function showScore() {
    const percentageScore = (score / questions.length) * 100;

    const csrfToken = document.getElementById('csrf_token').value;

    let resultHtml = '';
    if (percentageScore < 70) {
        // Afficher un message d'échec si le score est inférieur à 70%
        const URL_pict = "static/images/failed_quiz.png";
        resultHtml = `
            <div class="app2"> 
                <img src="${URL_pict}" alt="Image du quiz échoué">
                <p>Vous avez obtenu ${percentageScore.toFixed(0)}% sur 100%! <br> Vous devez obtenir au moins 70% pour réussir.</p>
                <button id="restart-btn" class="btn btn-primary">Commencer le quiz à nouveau</button>
            </div>
        `;
    } else {
        // Afficher un message de réussite
        resultHtml = `
            <div class="app2"> 
                <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
                <p>Félicitations! Vous avez obtenu ${percentageScore.toFixed(0)}% sur 100%!</p>
                <a href="/learner_show_result"><button id="see-results-btn" class="btn btn-primary">Voir les résultats</button></a>
            </div>
        `;
    }

    quizContainer.innerHTML = resultHtml;

    // Attach event listener to restart button
    const restartButton = document.getElementById("restart-btn");
    if (restartButton) {
        restartButton.addEventListener("click", startQuiz);
    }

    // Submit the form after everything is set up
    submitFormIfNeeded(percentageScore, csrfToken);
}

function submitFormIfNeeded(percentageScore, csrfToken) {
    if (percentageScore >= 70) {

        const form = document.getElementById("score-form");

        if (form) {

            // Attach event listener to form submission
            form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
                event.preventDefault();

                const formData = new FormData(form);
                const csrfToken = document.getElementById('csrf_token').value;
                formData.append('csrf_token', csrfToken);
                fetch('/submit_quiz', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: formData
                })
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(data => {
                        // Handle response if needed
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.error(error);
                        document.getElementById('feedback_message').innerHTML = `
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                <span class="closeBtn" onclick="closeAlert(this);">×</span>
                                <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
                                Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de la demande. Veuillez réessayer.
                            </div>`;
                    });
            });


            // Set the score value to the hidden input field
            const scoreInput = form.querySelector("#score");
            if (scoreInput) {
                scoreInput.value = score;
            }
            // Click the submit button automatically
            const submitButton = document.getElementById("submit-btn");
            submitButton.click();


        }
    }
}

// call fetchQuizesData initially to fetch the quiz data
fetchQuizesData();


your server is sending an HTML page where your client expects JSON - your code is mostly unreadable, so ... I tried to fix it to split the python html and JS for you

Check whether request.headers.get('X-Requested-With') contains what you expect. If it's not XMLHttpRequest you return an HTML template insead of JSON.

Thank you I fixed my problem by moving the submit_result() inside the show_exam() and added a condition:                                                                       if request.headers.get('X-Requested-With') == 'XMLHttpRequest':                           # code...                                                                                                                              elif request.method == 'POST':                                                                                    # code...
